# Squirrel: UnityJDBC throwing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: squirrel-sql

I've using Squirrel SQL 3.6.

I have working connections to two databases, which I'll call A and B.  I can run queries against A and B without issues.  They've been setup and working for a couple years.

I'm needing to run queries against both of these datasources/connections and have Squirrel handle the joins between them.

I've got the UnityJDBC driver added.  I've created a connection using same.  The next step is to add A and B to it, such that I can run queries across them.

I open the connection, right-click and select "(Virtualization) Add Source" and select A from the list, then tell it to "Add."  I don't add any other properties.

It tells me:

```
Preparing to add data source...

ClassNotFoundException for Driver: com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver

Make sure driver is in your classpath.
```

If that driver wasn't in the classpath, I'm assuming I wouldn't be able to use connection A at all.  Which leads me to believe UnityJDBC has another classpath all its own.  Any suggestions on what that would be, where to find it, how to fix this, etc?

Answer (score 0):

As said in this instruction http://www.unityjdbc.com/squirrel/MultiSourceVirtualizationPlugin_install.pdf :

> Make sure to add other database JDBC jars into the squirrel/lib folder
>   or JRE classpath. The plugin cannot access drivers in custom
>   classpaths used by SQuirreL.

Hope it's not too late and helps ;)

Comment: More than 6 months after I posted that question, you answered.  THANK YOU!  I'm running under Linux so I used ln -s to link the driver from its location to the /lib/ folder.  And that cleared the error.  If I can finish getting this working, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.